# Why does sequelize use a different name for foreign key columns?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm having an issue where sequelize is using an "inferred" name for foreign key columns rather than the column name defined in the model and used in the database.

This is happening on upsert and findAll.

As an example, given the following model:

```
Parent.hasMany(Child, {
    as: 'parentChildren',
    foreignKey: { field: 'fkParentId', allowNull: false },
    constraints: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
```

When I upsert a Child, sequelize expects the upsert JSON to use the name "parentId" for the foreign key field.

Similarly, if when I do a Child.findAll (with only a simple where condition), the JSON result uses the name "parentId" for the field. In my database log, I can see sequelize FORCING the name to parentId, for example:

```
SELECT field 1, field 2, etc, fkParentId AS parentId
```

I've tried defining both sides of the relationship by adding Child.belongsTo, and I've tried using sourceKey/targetKey, but this makes no difference.

Is there any way to make sequelize accept and return the actual name of the column?

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the documentation for the association it looks like you just have a field mismatch.  See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-hasMany -- it looks as if the key to set the name of the foreign key row in the database is actually the `name` key (if you are using an object for the `foreignKey` as opposed to just a string).

Try using this...

```
Parent.hasMany(Child, {
  as: 'parentChildren',
  foreignKey: { name: 'fkParentId', allowNull: false },
  constraints: true,
  onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
```

I have more experience with Sequelize 3.x.x but that should work for 4.x.x.  If that doesn't work then I know for a fact if you use a string for the `foreignKey` item in the association function call that it will set the name of the column as you want it to.

If that is the case then you can actually manually create the column in the attributes list of the Child model and use the string `foreignKey` that I mentioned above.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use otherKey here

```
Parent.hasMany(Child, {
    as: 'parentChildren',
    foreignKey: { field: 'fkParentId', allowNull: false },
    otherKey: 'fkParentId'
    constraints: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
```